# Decompressing mp3 frames

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio

I am trying to play a MP3 by decompressing it from a `MemoryStream` but for an unknown reason the mp3 frames are always null.

```
private MemoryStream audioStream = new MemoryStream();

public void FillMemoryStream(){
    OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFile.ShowDialog();

    FileStream f = new FileStream(openFile.FileName, FileMode.Open);
    f.CopyTo(audioStream);
}
```

So in `FillMemoryStream` method I open a mp3 file and I write all the bytes to that `MemoryStream` called `audioStream`.

```
private void StreamMp3(object state)
{            
        fullyDownloaded = true;
        var url = (string)state;

        var buffer = new byte[16384 * 4]; // needs to be big enough to hold a decompressed frame

        IMp3FrameDecompressor decompressor = null;

        try
        {
            using (audioStream)
            {
                var readFullyStream = new ReadFullyStream(audioStream);
                do
                {
                    if (IsBufferNearlyFull)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Buffer getting full, taking a break");
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Mp3Frame frame;
                        try
                        {
                            frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(readFullyStream);
                        }
                        catch (EndOfStreamException)
                        {
                            fullyDownloaded = true;
                            // reached the end of the MP3 file / stream
                            break;
                        }
                        if (decompressor == null)
                        {
                            decompressor = CreateFrameDecompressor(frame);
                            bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(decompressor.OutputFormat);
                            bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
                        }
                        int decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, buffer, 0);
                        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, decompressed);
                    }

                } while (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped);
                decompressor.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (decompressor != null)
            {
                decompressor.Dispose();
            }
        }
}
```

I used the methods from NAudio MP3StreamingDemo with modification that instead of using an `HttpWebResponse` stream I used a `MemoryStream`. Why is my "frame" always null ?

P.S. I don't want to use `Mp3FileReader` in order to open file because the source of the mp3 will comes from an udp connection .

UPDATE:

Even if I change `FillMemoryStream` to this

```
OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
openFile.ShowDialog();

Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(openFile.FileName);

reader.CopyTo(audioStream, 4096);
```

my frame is still null.

Comment: Just a silly question: Do you reset the position of the MemoryStream back to 0 after writing to it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks @ioclTR I forget about it ! Problem solved .